# Database relationship stopping a INSERT query from functioning

Tags: sql, relationship, insert-query

I'm currently working on a Database and just want to perform a VERY simple insert query.

My database is constructed like the following:

3 Tables:

```
(Table name: Fields)

Candidate: CID,Name,Surname,Gender
Voter:     VID,Name,Surname,Grade,Section,Gender,Password
Vote:      CID,VID,Category
```

`Candidate` is linked to `Vote` with `CID` being the foreign key in `Vote`.
`Voter` is Linked to `Vote` with `VID` being the foreign key in `Vote`.

The relationship between `Candidate` and `Vote` is 1 - Many
The relationship between `Voter` and `Vote` is 1 - Many

```
Data types:
CID = Number
VID = text
and the rest text.
```

My query is the following:

```
Insert into Vote (CID,VID,Catagory) VALUES(1,'James','Headboy');
```

Now this is the catch:

The query runs 100% when I remove the 1 - many relationshop between Vote and Voter.
When the relationship is in tact Access throws me a error saying:

Microsoft Access set 0 fields to Null due to a type conversion failure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that the only error message content? Also you misspelled `category` in your query, which I'm assuming is only a typo when posting the question

Comment: i am sensing a mismatch data type. are you able to show us your schema?

Comment: I can't promise that it will solve your problem, but if I was implementing this, I would include another field in the `Vote` table, to act as a numeric auto-incrementing primary key. It wouldn't surprise me if the lack of a primary key is hurting you here.

Comment: Also, you would probably be much better off in the long run if you have a numeric auto-incrementing primary key for your `Voter` table. Keeping strings unique can lead to some weird stuff down the line, especially since these seem to be names (and are thus pretty likely to encounter some level of repetition).

Comment: I'm not using this database as is. IT is being used by a JAVA program the does not allow repetition. Though what i did mention in the above statement was done in ACCESS